# Как реализовать такое?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var btn = this;
    if (btn.loaded) {
      $(btn).prev("div").html(btn.originalContent);
      btn.loaded = false;
      $(btn).text('Get Dynamic chart');
    } else {
      btn.originalContent = $(btn).prev("div").html();
      $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
      $.get($(btn).data("url"), function(html) {
        $(btn).prev("div").html(html);
        $(btn).prop('disabled', false).text('Закрыть');
        btn.loaded = true;
      });
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <h2>Dynamic chart1</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=1">Get Dynamic chart1</button>

<div id="div2">
  <h2>Dynamic chart2</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=2">Get Dynamic chart2</button>

<div id="div3">
  <h2>Dynamic chart3</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=3">Get Dynamic chart3</button>

<div id="div4">
  <h2>Dynamic chart4</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=4">Get Dynamic chart4</button>

<div id="div5">
  <h2>Dynamic chart5</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=5">Другая кнопка</button>
```

Так вот, `Кнопка 5` имеет отличное от всех название, но при нажатии на нее название скриптом меняется на `"Закрыть"`, это нормально. Но после нажатия кнопки закрыть, название кнопке присваивается скриптом на `Get Dynamic chart` заместо `"Другая кнопка"`, то-бишь родное название не превалирует. Как сделать что-бы у 5 кнопки до нажатия и после нажатия имена не присваивались скриптом или же как `5-й кнопке` присвоить в скрипте свои названия `на открытие`, `закрытие` и `возврат к исходному названию`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$btn.text( $btn.attr("data-close") || "Закрыть" );` — Если вручную в data-атрибуте задали текст для кнопки-закрывашки, возьмется он, иначе - значение по умолчанию.

```js
$("button").each(function() {
  this.dataset.HTML = this.innerHTML; 
  /* Оригинальный HTML можно отдельно сохранить... */

  $(this).on("click", function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var btn = this;

    if (btn.loaded) {
      $btn.prev("div").html(btn.originalContent);
      $btn.html( btn.dataset.HTML );
      btn.loaded = false;
    } else {
      btn.originalContent = $(btn).prev("div").html();
      $btn.prop('disabled', true);
      $.get($btn.data("url"), function(html) {
        $btn.prev("div").html(html);
        $btn.prop('disabled', false).text($btn.attr("data-close") || "Закрыть");
        btn.loaded = true;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <h2>Dynamic chart1</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=1"><img src="http://drako.ru/game/shared/data/smiles_extPicture/meow.png"></button>

<div id="div2">
  <h2>Dynamic chart2</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=2"><img src="http://drako.ru/game/shared/data/smiles_extPicture/meow.png"></button>

<div id="div3">
  <h2>Dynamic chart3</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=3"><img src="http://drako.ru/game/shared/data/smiles_extPicture/meow.png"></button>

<div id="div4">
  <h2>Dynamic chart4</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=4"><img src="http://drako.ru/game/shared/data/smiles_extPicture/meow.png"></button>

<div id="div5">
  <h2>Dynamic chart5</h2>
</div>
<button data-close="Закрыть подписку" data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=5">Другая кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, скажите что в этом коде  $btn.text( $btn.attr("data-open") || "Get Dynamic chart" );   нужно изменить чтобы заместо Get Dynamic chart  что-бы была иконка? Я пробовал вот так  .prepend('<img id="theImg" src="grafik.jpg" class=" lazyload" style="width: 30px;height: 30px;overflow:hidden;" />');  но у меня ничего не получилось. Это мне нужно для обычных кнопок. Спасибо

Comment: `var src = $btn.attr("data-img") || "картинка_по_умолчанию.png"; $btn.html( '<img src="' + src + '">' + " какой-то_текст" );`

Comment: Спасибо большое, а Вы можете это в Вашем ответе (в коде) отразить, с уважением

Comment: после того как я нажал на иконку, появляется кнопка Закрыть, нажимаю на нее, а заместо иконки появляется текст Get Dynamic chart заместо Иконки

Comment: Хотя нет, что-то не так идет.(

Comment: @Arcadiy отредактировал ответ, но вопрос получился про одно, а ответ про другое))

Comment: Она превращается вот в такой код, у нее внутри картинка <button data-open="Подписаться" data-close="Закрыть подписку" name="Подписаться на авиабилеты" data-url="/uvedomlenie.php?a=9" style="margin: 0px auto !important;padding: 0px;display: inline-block;background: white;color: steelblue;border: 0px;font-size: 18px;/*! padding: 15px; */padding: 17px 15px;border-radius: 4px;"><img src="Подписаться"></button>

Comment: Вам спасибо огромное, но почему-то не так работает

Comment: @Arcadiy Отредактировано... Первый, второй и третий варианты - три разных вопроса =_=

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо!